# jxl.WritableCellFormat definition

Tags: java, excel, cell, writable

Is it possible to create one jxl.WritableCellFormat attribute which contains Font, NumberFormat, BackgroundColor and Border?

This works:

```
public static final NumberFormat numberformatter = new NumberFormat("#,###0.00");  
public static final WritableFont defaultfont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TAHOMA, 10); 
public static final WritableCellFormat numberCellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(defaultfont, numberformatter); '
```

but I can't get borders and colors, thought same kind of cell is needed many times when creating sheets.

Comment: Please consider creating an account.  Once you do, @Will here and I'll merge your unregistered accounts together so you can access your questions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the border and background via the `WritableCellFormat.setBorder()` and `WritableCellFormat.setBackground()` methods after having instanciated your cell.

You can see the API [there](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableCellFormat.html).

If you have to do that a lot, you can make a helper function like this :

```
public static makeCell(NumberFormat format, WritableFont font, Color backgrd, Border border){
    final WritableCellFormat result = new WritableCellFormat(defaultfont, numberformatter);
    result.setBorder(border);
    result.setBackground(backgrd);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I know that, but where I do it nicely? If I get the other formats via getter, how I but the borders so that I don't do it everytime again when i call addcell methods?

Comment: Well you can't invent API methods which are not there. You'll need to make yourself a function that does the job, having the correct arguments, and call that function everytime you need that to be done.

Comment: the OP was asking if you can give an example of calling the method and adding the formatted cell to sheet.

Comment: from OP:  Can you give me an example of calling this method and adding the formatted cell to sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You Can do this by 2 steps

1. Create a WritableFont
2. Create a WritableCellFormat with WritableFont,NumberFormats as a parameter

Attaching the code snippet

```
int fontSize = 8;  
WritableFont wfontStatus = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, fontSize);
wfontStatus.setColour(Colour.BLACK);
wfontStatus.setBoldStyle(WritableFont.BOLD);

WritableCellFormat fCellstatus = new WritableCellFormat(wfontStatus, NumberFormats.TEXT); // You can use any NumberFormats I have used TEXT for my requirement
try {
    fCellstatus.setWrap(true);
    fCellstatus.setBorder(Border.ALL,BorderLineStyle.THIN);
    fCellstatus.setAlignment(Alignment.CENTRE);
    fCellstatus.setBackground(Colour.YELLOW);
} 
catch (WriteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```